# How to zip individual folders present in a particular folder using perl?

Tags: regex

Can please someone help me out with this.....

I have my folders say A,B,C inside D:\Zip.
I need to zip A.zip, B.zip & C. zip. The below is the code i tried.
CODE:

```
enter code here
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Cwd;
use File::Copy;
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError) ;

use File::Basename 'basename';
my $path1=getcwd;
my $zipfile=getcwd."\.zip";
my $zip;

opendir(DIR, "$path1\/");
my $mainFolder=grep(/"$path1\/"/,readdir(DIR));
close DIR;

#### Zip Module #####
my $f2;
my $newzipname=$mainFolder;
print $mainFolder."\n";

foreach my $f($mainFolder)
{
print $f."\n";  
print $mainFolder."asfsd\n";    
my $zip=Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->addTree( "$f" );
die 'write error' unless $zip->writeToFileNamed($path1.'.zip') == AZ_OK;
exit 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Cwd;
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
use File::Spec;

my $path=getcwd;

opendir(DIR, $path);

while (my $entry = readdir DIR) {
    my $fullpath = File::Spec->catdir($path,$entry);
    next unless -d $fullpath;
    next if $entry eq '.' or $entry eq '..';
    my $zip=Archive::Zip->new();
    $zip->addTree($fullpath);
    die 'write error' unless $zip->writeToFileNamed($fullpath.'.zip') == AZ_OK;
}

close DIR;
```

Comment: Thanks, It works..But for one of the folder it is creating Thumbs.db, which needs to be deleted. I tried writing this, but still it's not getting deleted. CODE:                            foreach my $entry($path)
 {
  if(-e "$path\/Thumbs.db") 
  {
   unlink("$path\/Thumbs.db") or die "Thumbs.db Cannot be deleted"; 
  }
 }

Comment: If `Thumbs.db` is a directory, you'd need to do something like `use File::Path qw(remove_tree); remove_tree(File::Spec->catdir($path,'Thumbs.db'));` -- unlink only works on regular files/links.

Comment: the code is working fine... some change is there now in the requirement i.e it is creating a copy of the original file and zipping it. but we need to zip directly the original file i.e A.zip\A\contents inside folder A.